# Android: permission denied for window type 2038

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to create float overlaying space in android. I have:

```
targetSdkVersion 30
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

I registered a service with

```
<service
    android:name=".service.RecordService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection">
</service>
```

and run it with

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecordService.class);
                intent.putExtra("cmd","start service");
                startService(intent);
                mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, intent);
```

and all of it breaking on

```
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getApplication().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams();
        mLayoutParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        mLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
        mLayoutParams.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        mLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mLayoutParams.x = 0;
        mLayoutParams.y = 0;
        mLayoutParams.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        mLayoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication());
        mFloatLayout = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_record,null);
        mStartBtn = (TextView)mFloatLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        mStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecordService.this, RecordService.class);
                intent.putExtra("cmd","start recording");
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        mFloatLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatLayout, mLayoutParams);
```

on the last line :(
What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use also

```
mLayoutParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
mLayoutParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
```

but with the same problem:

```
Process: com.poqdev.screenrec, PID: 20517
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.poqdev.screenrec.service.RecordService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@90e7698 -- permission denied for window type 2038
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4204)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@90e7698 -- permission denied for window type 2038
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1092)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:409)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
        at com.poqdev.screenrec.service.RecordService.createFloatView(RecordService.java:145)
        at com.poqdev.screenrec.service.RecordService.onCreate(RecordService.java:66)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4192)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Hi this might be a bit late, but I had the same issue and I found that you have to give your app the "Display over other apps" permission inside of Settings. Once you set this to Allowed, then you should not see this error.